What should I feed my saltwater snails? How do I know how much to add?
I have a Nassarius snail and two snails of unknown origin (Astrae and Nirite perhaps?).
I know the Nassarius eats tropical meat. I used to keep the snails with some brine shrimp and assumed they ate the same thing.
However, they are now in a tank without brine shrimp and I am uncertain how to keep them fed. Do I just give them half a algae wafer? I don't want to overfeed them either.
Are seaweed okay or do they need a more diverse pallet?
Should I only stick to specific types of wafers? Or are all algae wafers the same?
Thank you so much for any help.
